# How do you ensure a <td> is exactly 200px tall?

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I have a table with an image inside:

```
<table style="border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 800px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-collapse: collapse;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"><img style="width: 800px; height: 200px; border: 0px;" alt="Logo" src="logo.png">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

No matter what I do, there is still a little sliver of white at the bottom of the image. A quick check with Chrome's Inspector reveals that the `td` has a height of `204px`!

How can I force the `td` to be the same height as the image?

As you can see above, I've tried all sorts of things...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:** Add "vertical-align:bottom;" to the image style.
Another solution, not always suitable, is to change the image `display` type to `block`, instead of it's original `inline` display type.
**Explanation:** The problem occurs due to the automatic behavior of browsers that add a space under the text for characters that are longer than usual. The image is an inline object like text, thus it has a space underneath too.
A great explanation [is written in quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html):

> **Complication: almost strict mode**
>
> In the early days, experiments with
>   strict mode invariably raised the
>   comment that images suddenly got an
>   odd bottom margin that couldn’t be
>   removed. The cause was that in strict
>   mode  is an inline element,
>   which means that some space should be
>   reserved for possible descender
>   characters like g, j, or q. Of course
>   an image doesn’t have descender
>   characters, so the space was never
>   used, but it still had to be reserved.
>
> The solution was to explicitly declare
>   images block level elements: img
>   {display: block}.
>
> Nonetheless browser vendors, Mozilla
>   especially, thought this was such a
>   confusing situation that they
>   introduced "almost strict mode". This
>   was defined as strict mode, but with
>   images continuing to be blocks, and
>   not inline elements.
>
> Most common doctypes, including the
>   one I use, trigger almost strict mode.
>   The treatment of images is by far the
>   most important difference between
>   almost strict mode and really strict
>   mode.

Generally you should use a CSS reset document that avoids problems such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

You'll live a far happier life if you give up the idea that you can create pixel-perfect layouts with HTML.

If you really need pixel precision, you might try tossing the `table` and using absolute positioning via CSS instead.

Comment: Isn't there some way to do this? This is Chrome, not even IE!

Comment: Of course there is. It's no problem to create pixel-perfect layouts in HTML, you just have to know how.

Comment: Not really, no. Differences between browsers make it all but impossible, and HTML (especially `table`, which is intended for tabular data, not layout) was never intended to provide that level of control. Instead, it's supposed to allow the user agent to display pages in a way that makes sense in a particular context (mobile vs. desktop, for instance).

You can *usually* beat a given page into submission, but it is never as easy as people coming from a desktop app background would expect.

Comment: the beating into submission part I agree with - it's often bizarrely hard work, and a process of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
table
{
table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Comment: have you also added <td style="width:200px"   ?

Answer (score 0):

It's 200px tall for me. Can you post an online example?

If it's 4 pixels difference, I'm pretty sure the culprit is what used to be the `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` HTML attributes. Can you try setting those to 0 just to see whether it works? The CSS equivalent to that might be border-spacing but I can't try out because it works for me.

Comment: No, unfortunately neither the CSS `border-spacing` nor the `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` attributes work.

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm testing this on Chrome.

Comment: @George I tested it on Chrome as well but with an image that wouldn't load - which seems to behave differently than one that does.